# Passing value correctly to PHP from AJAX Code

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, api

So I'm trying to pass a value from my AJAX code to my PHP code which connects to an API to get the weather. It works when just using PHP, but I want ajax to return the results to some div on the same page. My code looks correct when I compare it to other examples but it just doesn't work.

Code may not be written with security in mind, standard practice etc, I'm just trying to play around with API's and get the basics of AJAX.
api.php:

```
  $city = $_POST['city'];

  function getCityLat($x) {
    $latUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. $x .'APIKEY';

    $latResponse = file_get_contents($latUrl);
    $latArray = json_decode($latResponse, true);

    $lat = $latArray['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
echo $lat;
    return $lat;
  }

  function getCityLng($y) {
    $lngUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. $y .'APIKEY';

    $lngResponse = file_get_contents($lngUrl);
    $lngArray = json_decode($lngResponse, true);

    $lng = $lngArray['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    echo $lng;
    return $lng;
  }

  function getWeather($x, $y) {
    $weatherUrl = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/' . $x . ',' . $y;
    $weatherResponse = file_get_contents($weatherUrl);

    $weatherArray = json_decode($weatherResponse, true);

    $timeZone = $weatherArray['timezone'];
    $locWeather = $weatherArray['currently']['temperature'];
    $locFeelsLike = $weatherArray['currently']['apparentTemperature'];
    $windSpeed = $weatherArray['currently']['windSpeed'];
    $weatherSummary = $weatherArray['currently']['summary'];
    $time = $weatherArray['currently']['time'];

    $outputweather = '<p>Temp: '.$locWeather.'</p>';
    echo $outputweather;
  }

  getWeather(getCityLat($city), getCityLng($city));

?>
```

index.php(html):

```
<h3 align="center">Weather</h3>
    <form align="center" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Enter City">
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" name="city_go" id="city_go">Go</button>
    </form>
  <div id="weather"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
function getWeather(city) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "api.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {city:city}, 
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#weather').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

   $(document).on('click', '#city_go', function() {
    var city = $('#city').val();
    getWeather(city);
  });
```

Comment: replace   getWeather(getCityLat($city), getCityLng($city));
with  echo getWeather(getCityLat($city), getCityLng($city)); die; and check

Comment: Thanks for the reply! that didn't work :(

Did I need to do anything after die; 
?

Comment: Once check in network-> xhr if you are gettting anything

Comment: Not getting anything when I hit go after typing in the city I want :( I don't understand why it isn't working

Comment: in network->xhr i mean

Comment: replace data: {city:city} with data: {'city':city}

Comment: user1544541 THAT WORKED!! :D the data from the api flashed onto my index.php and then dissappeared so I'm on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: No still not working :( it worked once, then stopped working altogether

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are submitting a form, which forces a page refresh. Everything else is working correctly, just the page is being refreshed. To fix that you need to update your click event to something like

```
$(document).on('click', '#city_go', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    getWeather(city);
});
```

the preventDefault() call will cancel the default action of the form (the page refresh) and allow the AJAX call to follow through and display the data.